# Jenkins schedule JOBS based on week

Tags: jenkins, cron, integration, schedule

How do I schedule dependent jobs in Jenkins. I cant schedule it as 1st week , 2nd week or 3rd week to maintain the number of runs. We want the schedule weekly.

Job1 to run on week1

Job2 to run on week2

Job3 to run on week3

Again,

Job1 to run on week4

Job2 to run on week5

Job3 to run on week6.

And the schedule goes on ..

How do I script this in Jenkins "Build Periodically".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you could do this with a cron expression. I think the best you could do is setup a weekly job and then use logic to execute the appropriate build.

You could either use a pipeline job, the conditional build step plugin, or if you really need them to be entirely separate jobs, build a pipeline job that runs weekly, decides which job to run, and then kicks off the appropriate job using the "build" step. You have much more powerful logic available to you this way, instead of just a cron expression.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the format to schedule jobs Weekly and Monthly**

**MINUTE (0-59), HOUR (0-23), DAY (1-31), MONTH (1-12), DAY OF THE WEEK (0-6)**

1. Weekday daily build twice a day, at lunchtime 12:00 and midnight 00:00, Sunday to Thursday: 00 0,12 * * 0-4
2. Every first of every month between 2:00 a.m. - 02:30 a.m.: H(0,30) 02 01 * *